Перевод русского текста в речь
Здесь пример кода, который преобразует текст в речь.
import pyttsx3
tts = pyttsx3.init()
voices = tts.getProperty('voices')
# Задать голос по умолчанию
tts.setProperty('voice', 'ru') 
# Попробовать установить предпочтительный голос
for voice in voices:
    if voice.name == 'Aleksandr':
        tts.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
tts.say('Привет, Мир!')
tts.runAndWait()

На английском языке работает корректно, но на русском молчание.
Значок "Преобразование текста в речь" в параметрах Windows 10 имеется, но в Python русский текст не произносится 

так нужно же смотреть не распознавание, а преобразование текста в речь.

@Alex Alex Вы правы. Преобразование текста в речь имеется, но всё равно воспроизводится только английская речь

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977155/change-pyttsx3-language . по ссылке показано, как получить зарегеистрированные голоса в системе. а потом выставить нужный id
